# Tips optimizing my python graph creation code

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

My programming task is to, given an input file `words.txt`, create a graph where the nodes are the words themselves, and edges are words with one letter different. (eg. "abcdef" and "abcdeg" would have an edge).

For later stages of the problem, I really need to use the adjacency list implementation (so no adjacency matrix). I'd prefer not to use external libraries if possible.

My code is functional, but takes about 7 seconds to run (for ~5000 words). I need help optimizing it further. The main optimization I did was using sets with {"index,char"} for each char in the string and compared the sets, which was a lot faster than something like `sum(x!=y for x,y in zip(word1, word2))`

This is the code I have so far:

```
def createGraph(filename):
    """Time taken to generate graph: {} seconds."""
    wordReference = {} # Words and their smartsets (for comparisons)
    wordEdges = {} # Words and their edges (Graph representation)
    edgeCount = 0 # Count of edges
    with open(filename) as f:
        for raw in f.readlines(): # For each word in the file (Stripping trailing \n)
            word = raw.strip()
            wordReference[word] = set("{}{}".format(letter, str(i)) for i, letter in enumerate(word)) # Create smartsets in wordReference
            wordEdges[word] = set() # Create a set to contain the edges
            for parsed in wordEdges: # For each of the words we've already parsed
                if len(wordReference[word] & wordReference[parsed]) == 5: # If compare smartSets to see if there should be an edge
                    wordEdges[parsed].add(word) #Add edge parsed -> word
                    wordEdges[word].add(parsed) #Add edge word -> parsed
                    edgeCount += 1 #Add 1 to edgesCount
    return wordEdges, edgeCount, len(wordReference) #Return dictionary of words and their edges
```

Comment: Why not use external libraries? These are usually optimized.